# Plesk Scheduled Tasks - Deny: Previous script did not finished yet

Tags: plesk, plesk-onyx

I had a script added to the Plesk's scheduled task, then, I removed it from the scheduled task, but it was still running in background and using lots of CPU, so I killed it via shell `htop`, Now I am trying to add that script back to the scheduled task again, But when I run it I am getting following error

> Deny: Previous script did not finished yet

I have tried deleting the entries from "longtasks" table via a shell command

```
 plesk db "delete from longtasks"
```

But that didn't work.

I have the following version of Plesk and operating system on my server

Plesk Version: Onyx 17.8

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 Server LTS

ScreenShot of error
[image]

please Let me know if anybody have any suggestion, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script is finished properly, as far as Plesk concerns, while `Deny: Previous script did not finished yet` message is the output of the script itself.

Try running it manually to make sure, and then review its's content to fing why it is not executing as expected.